# Why did the Rohirrim throw his spear?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie

In the film LOTR: The Two Towers, there's a scene where Merry and Pippin are saved by a Rohirrim who throws his spear into the body of an orc that was about to kill them.

The Rohorrim then charge in on horseback and use their spears and swords as skirmishing weapons at short range. Now, obviously the Rohirrim didn't know Merry and Pip were saved this by spear throw and Eomer even said (to Aragorn) that they saw no Hobbits during the attack.

**So why did that particular Rohirrim throw his spear so early?**

Comment: Question edited to reflect that you're interested in knowing why it happened **in the film**.

Comment: There's nothing in any of the multitude of commentaries that addresses this, except in passing.

Comment: But it is easier to explain if you've read the books.  Orcs are a bit less intimidating there than they are in the movies.

Comment: Just a linguistic note: _Rohirrim_ means ‘the warriors of Rohan’ (or literally translated, it means ‘host of horse-lords’) and is inherently plural. A single member of the Rohirrim would be a **Rohîr** (horse-lord), or if you prefer to use endonyms instead of exonyms, an _Eorling_ (singular of _Eorlingas_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'm reading Two Towers right now and I'm up to the battle of Helm's Deep.  Gamling says "Helmingas" when he is trying to get men to defend the keep.  Does this mean "Helmsmen", "sons of Helm", or something like that?

Comment: @WadCheber No, the _-ing_ suffix means ‘son/descendant of’; so _Eorling(as)_ is ‘descendant(s) of Eorl’, first king of Rohan; and _Helming(as)_ is ‘descendant(s) of Helm (Hammerhand)’, after whom Helm’s Deep was named.

Comment: I just added that edit (the "sons of Helm" part) as you responded - great minds think alike

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also, "Khazad" seems to mean "dwarves", not "[a] dwarf".  When Gimli yells "Khazad ai menu" ("Dwarves are upon you") in Helm's Deep, isn't he technically misspeaking?  I assume it is a standard dwarf battlecry, but at HD, only one dwarf is upon the Orcs.

Comment: @WadCheber Technically, he is probably misspeaking, yes. But as battle cries go, “Beware! The dwarves are upon you!” sounds more impressive, and somehow does make sense (for a battle cry) even if it’s only one dwarf being upon them. And I believe that one phrase is all the Dwarvish we have from Tolkien himself—he may not have intended for there to be a singular/plural distinction in Dwarvish at all, though of course David Salo certainly made one for neo-Khuzdul.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - we have at least one more brief phrase, also a battlecry, although we see it directly preceding the phrase already mentioned.  Gimli first yells,  "Baruk Khazad! Khzad ai-menu!"  (Axes of the Dwarves!  The Dwarves are upon you!", and later yells "Khazad!  Khazad!", and later still, "Khazad ai-menu!".  I don't know if this comes from Tolkien himself, but Tolkien Gateway has an entry on Khuzd/Khazad that says:  Khuzd pl. Khazâd was the Khuzdul word for the "Dwarves"...In earlier versions, the plural was Khuzûd

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - considering Tolkien's professional background as a philologist/linguist, I would be shocked if he created a language - or even a tiny part of a language - without thinking about how pluralization would work

Comment: @WadCheber He might have deliberately created one that did not distinguish singular and plural at all, though. Many natural languages work like that. Without more samples, I don’t think we have any way of knowing for sure _what_ he intended (though I think David Salo’s guess is a good one—what little Dwarvish we do have does have rather a Semitic feel to it).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I started a new question to deal with this issue.  I humbly request that you bring your wealth of knowledge to the table and offer an answer.  I can't imagine anyone being better equipped than yourself to answer it.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89715/how-much-dwarvish-appears-in-tolkiens-work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is more obvious in the book than the movie, but when the Rohirrim engaged the Orcs, the Orcs were terrified and more interested in running away than fighting (in fact, in the book, the Rohirrim are so confident that, rather than killing the Orcs as soon as they catch up to them, they encircle the Orcs, set up camp, and go to sleep, then wait for sunrise before beginning the slaughter;  the Orcs don't attempt to attack during the night, but some of them do try to break out and flee - unsuccessfully).

The Rohirrim had the upper hand and everyone knew it.  The books say that there were 200-300 Orcs against a much smaller force of Rohirrim, yet the Rohirrim killed every last Orc and suffered only relatively minor losses - just 15 men died, compared to 200-300 Orcs.

In such a lopsided battle, the Rohirrim were confident enough to throw spears willy nilly and use their swords more than they would have if the enemy posed a more formidable threat.  It was almost like shooting fish in a barrel.  And of course, a spear designed for throwing - also called a javelin - is very different from a spear designed to be held and thrust at an enemy.  Throwing spears are shorter and lighter; thrusting spears are longer and heavier.  Trying to use a throwing spear or javelin as a lance will likely result in a broken spear.

In general, human warriors (and elf warriors, and dwarf warriors) in Middle-earth are far more skilled and formidable than Orc warriors (again, this is more obvious in the books than it is in the movies).  Orcs are terrifying, but there is a reason they tend to focus on raiding and pillaging civilian settlements, farms, etc, rather than engaging in set piece battles against hardened troops in numbers similar to their own - at least when they have a choice.  Killing women, children, old people, farmers, shopkeepers, etc, is a hell of a lot easier (and safer) than fighting against experienced warriors who know you're coming and have swords of their own.

Orcs are brave when they have a huge numerical advantage or when their targets are frightened, defenseless civilians, but in a fair fight against actual soldiers, they tend to be easily routed.  Imagine a street gang - they are tough enough to squabble with other gangs and terrorize their neighborhood, but how do you think the Crips would fare in a battle against the Marines?  Not very well.  In fact, they'd be wiped out in a few seconds.  The same basic dynamic loosely applies to Orcs - they're like a gang, and they can only hold their own against civilians or wildly outnumbered warriors.

The Rohirrim know all of this, and fight accordingly.  They knew that they would win without breaking a sweat, so they killed the Orcs off in the easiest manner possible.  Throwing a spear or two wouldn't affect the outcome either way, so there was no reason *not* to throw it.

Comment: Good answer. You have my +1

Comment: This also answered another question I have been thinking. In the scene that Aragorn met Eomer and his troop, Eomer gave them 2 horses whose owner were killed by orcs. He gave them 2 horses instead of 3 horses and there were 3 persons in the company. So I wondered : "Only 2 Rohirrims died from the battle?"

Comment: @Iamwaiman - The reason he gives only 2 horses is because Gimli has no riding skills and doesn't want a horse, prefering taking the ride with Legolas.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988: IIRC, 15 humans were killed in the battle, along with 12 horses.

Comment: @jamesqf - Without looking it up, I believe you're right.  If we assume that the Rohirrim started out with no extra horses (which would not happen in real life, but Tolkien gets horse-related stuff wrong sometimes), they would only have 3 horses to spare (15 men died and 12 horses died, therefore there are 3 horses without riders now).  But either way, Joel is correct - Dwarves don't like horses much, so Gimli always rides with someone else - in Two Towers, he rides with Legolas, Gandalf, and Eomer.

Comment: @Wad Cheber: Re "Gimli always rides with someone else", I think this yet again displays Tolkien's lack of practical horsemanship.  While I don't by any means claim to be an expert, I wouldn't try to ride double for any distance.  Hard on you (especially without a saddle!), and hard on the horse to carry double the weight.  Maybe Legolas and Gandalf don't weigh that much (being at least partly spiritual beings), but Eomer was a pretty hefty guy.

Comment: @jamesqf - This is true.  However, at least on the ride to the Fords of Isen (which is rerouted to Helm's Deep), they did stop to set up camp at night.  Dwarves are short but broad/stout, so 2 dwarves might not be so bad, and an elf and a dwarf might work, but a Rohir plus a dwarf is probably like one REALLY fat guy - like 400 lbs fat.  Gandalf plus Gimli is less of an issue because they were riding Shadowfax.

Comment: @Wad Cheber: Dwarves may be short, but they wear lots of ironmongery!  And from somewhere I've gotten the impression that their flesh is actually denser than human, so that it'd be impossible for a nude dwarf to float in water.  (Something that I've read is true of orangutans.)