# Did Tolkien invent enough Dwarvish to carry on a conversation?

Tags: languages, dwarves, tolkien-languages, j-r-r-tolkien, tolkiens-legendarium

I read the glossaries of the Lord of the Rings books and it said that the language spoken by the Dwarves was not spoken to others except for a few words. That got me wondering if Tolkien had ever even invented that language as a whole. Did he invent Dwarvish far enough to carry a conversation or not?

Comment: If he did, he never wrote it down nor told anyone about it. How can we possibly answer differently?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann The answer to that question, and [the linked page](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/khuzdul.htm) on the Dwarvish language, give you as much detail as is known about Tolkien's development of that language.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "inventing the language as a whole". Do you mean that he was able to, e.g., conjugate a verb in it? Write coherent sentences? Carry on a conversation? Teach a class? How much invention needs to go on before he's "invented the language as a whole"?

Comment: @MattGutting I mean by carrying on a conversation.

Comment: OK, that's better. That means something significant.

Comment: When I get stuck whilst conversing in dwarvish with my dwarf buddies, I just fill in the gaps with some Klingon mumbo jumbo. Nobody is one the wiser.

Comment: None of Tolkien's languages were developed enough that one can carry a conversation in them. (Even Quenya and Sindarin)

Comment: @ibid - Quenya, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenya#Vocabulary) has ~25,000 words... How is that not enough for a conversation? ... Or you mean a random conversation, instead of one that's made from the words we have?

Comment: @Malandy - A random conversation. If you were able to construct the conversion yourself than you would only need those hundred words or so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No

There simply aren't enough *words* in Tolkien's Khuzdûl to carry on a conversation. This is noted by Christopher Tolkien in *History of Middle-earth*, when remarking on the use of the language in the inscription on Balin's tomb:

> The use of the Dwarf-tongue (Khuzdul) is possible in so short an inscription, since this tongue has been sketched in some detail of structure, if with a very small vocabulary.
>
> <sup>*History of Middle-earth* XII *The Peoples of Middle-earth* Chapter X: "Of Dwarves and Men"</sup>

What little we know of the language is covered in Nerrolken's answer to [How much Dwarvish appears in Tolkien's work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89715/how-much-dwarvish-appears-in-tolkiens-work), and more generally on [Ardalambion](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/khuzdul.htm).

It's worth noting that the Khuzdûl we hear in *The Hobbit* film trilogy was constructed by [David Salo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Salo), a professional linguist with a passionate interest in Tolkien's languages. He discusses some of the challenges of this task on [his blog](http://midgardsmal.com/getting-started/), which is worth a read if you're interested in this sort of thing:

> When I was asked to come up with some Dwarvish-language lines and lyrics for The Lord of the Rings, I initially balked. It wasn't my first experience with constructing Khuzdul — I had invented some names for the Middle-earth Role Playing Game several years earlier — but that had been with the understanding that I was, in a sense, contributing to a new world, related to Tolkien's but not quite the same. This felt a bit different. I pointed out that the amount of written Khuzdul could fit on a couple of pages (this is still basically true) and that almost nothing was known about its structure. I said that whatever I wrote in it would be largely a new invention, and that I wasn't going to pass it off as Tolkien's own work. I got the go-ahead anyway, and plunged in.

Comment: It should also be noted that this answer applies to all of Tolkien's other languages as well.